# inherit and customize a windows forms trackbar control

Tags: winforms

I am trying to put together a windows forms control for an abacus simulator. I thought to just use trackbar controls stacked on top of each other with a max value of 1, but when I stack the controls on top of each other, the only thumb you can see after dragging them into a value of 1 is the top one (the other 4 are hidden by the top one). I thought maybe I could just change the background of the controls to transparent (found another post all about that and that didn't work). Basically I just want to customize a trackbar for stacking that is only clickable on the thumb and everything but the thumb is transparent. Can anyone give me a lead to follow?

Thanks

Comment: Even if you succeed in creating transparent trackbars which you probably can't, it is extremelly difficult, you have to handle the collision of thumbs another difficult task.

Comment: I think you'd be better off trying to arrange them so they don't overlap.  Either with TrackBar or custom controls.  Could you post an image of what you'd like to look like?